# Does every diagonal intersection contain $0$?

Tags: notation, set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

This might even be a notational nuisance, but here it goes.

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal, $X_\alpha\subseteq\kappa$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$. As you know, the *diagonal intersection* of $\{X_\alpha\}_\alpha$ is the set
$$
\triangle_\alpha X_\alpha := \{\xi\in\kappa : \xi\in \textstyle\bigcap_{\alpha<\xi} X_\alpha\}.
$$
Now, does $0$ belong to this set?

It should be the case when $0\in\bigcap_{\alpha<0} X_\alpha = \bigcap \emptyset$, which is undefined, or $\emptyset$ by convention (in some books). In the last case, I would conclude that $0\notin\triangle_\alpha X_\alpha$; but there are comments both in Kunen and in Jech that imply the contrary. For instance, Jech writes (after the previous definition)
$$
\triangle_\alpha X_\alpha=\textstyle\bigcap_\alpha(X_\alpha\cup\{\xi:\xi\leq\alpha\}).
$$
Actually, if you define $\bigcap$ as a function from classes to classes, $\bigcap \emptyset = V$ makes perfect sense, but even there Jech takes care of restricting its domain to nonempty classes.

A meta-question: Is there some context where this matters?

Comment: I don't see why Jech's definition implies that zero is not in the diagonal intersection - because it uses "$\le$" instead of "$<$", $0$ is in $X_\alpha\cup\{\xi: \xi\le\alpha\}$ for every $\alpha$, and so is in the diagonal intersection.

Comment: @NoahSchweber His _definition_ is the first one (same as Kunen's). The second displayed equation is a comment. The same happens in the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_intersection)

Comment: Do some books really define $\bigcap \emptyset=\emptyset$?  I've never seen any definition other than $\bigcap \emptyset=V$ (or whatever smaller universe of discourse all the sets you're talking about might be subsets of, which would be $\kappa$ in this case).

Comment: @EricWofsey $\emptyset$ is a default value for partial functions when taking arguments outside of their domain. This simplifies the treatment of recursion, etc.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Let me rephrase that: I don't see the contradiction between his *comment* and the definition. They seem to agree that $0$ is in the diagonal intersection, always.

Comment: And I second Eric: can you give a citation? I've never seen $\bigcap\emptyset$ defined as anything other than $V$ (or a smaller domain of discourse). This gibes with the fact that $\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$ is a *class* (that is, a collection of sets defined by a formula), which *in case $I$ is nonempty* is a set.

Comment: I actually *do* recall a situation where $\bigcap\varnothing=\varnothing$ was assumed. I want to say Devlin's Constructibility. But I can't be sure. You can get this to be a reasonable definition if you define $$\bigcap A=\{a\in\bigcup A\mid\forall X\in A: a\in A\},$$ then in the case of $A=\varnothing$ you get $\varnothing$ again.

Comment: This is very much a matter of convention, and carries no weight in applications. Some authors define diagonal intersections of subsets of $\kappa$ explicitly excluding zero: $\triangle_\alpha X_\alpha=\{\xi\in\kappa\mid 0<\xi\land\forall \alpha<\xi\,(\xi\in X_\alpha)\}$. It is typical nowadays to identify sets that coincide up to a nonstationmary set, which of course makes moot the question of whether $0$ is in the diagonal intersection.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Thanks. I'll add this to question later; I'll wait just if someone wants to say something in this vein in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

All the definitions given seem to agree that $0$ is always in the diagonal intersection. The sets

> $\{\xi\in\kappa: \xi\in\bigcap_{\alpha<\xi}X_\alpha\}$

and

> $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\kappa}(X_\alpha\cup\{\xi: \xi\le\alpha\})$

are the same set; in particular, $0$ is in the latter, since for every $\alpha\in\kappa$ we have $\alpha\ge0$, so $0\in\{\xi: \xi\le\alpha\}$ and hence is in $X_\alpha\cup\{\xi: \xi\le\alpha\}$.

I don't see any definition which makes $0$ *not* an element of the diagonal intersection, and I don't see any remark in Jech or Kunen where this is contradicted.

Comment: In Kunen (1980), p.13 $\bigcap\mathcal{F}$ is (only) defined for sets $\mathcal{F}\neq\emptyset$. Then, in p.23 he states that _“We consider partially defined operations [...] to be defined to be 0 outside their natural domains.”_ This makes $\bigcap\emptyset = 0$.

Comment: Ah. Well, that is a bit weird in my opinion. For what it's worth, I can't think of a single case where it actually matters whether $0$ is in the diagonal intersection.

Comment: I thought so, that's why I added this as a meta-question. I also confirmed that Kunen is consistent in his new _Set Theory_ (2013), where the same two observations appear. If you want to incorporate these things into your answer, it will be acceptable for me. In any case, thanks for it.